# How to check if a URL contains /preview or the subdomain is CI?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a Regex to check if a URL contains either `ci`, `ci1`, `ci2` or `stag`

or

If the url contains `/preview`

https://regex101.com/r/aKHx9g/2/tests

For example, the regex should match

```
http://ci.company.com
http://stag.company.com
http://www.company.com/preview
https://www.company.com/preview
```

This one shouldn't match

```
http://www.company.com/article
http://company.com/article
https://company.com/article
```

Not sure if regex is able to catch that?

I can't seem to figure out to do a `OR` condition in regex. Here's what I have got so far.

```
https?:\/\/(ci|stag|ci2|ci3)\..*
```

Comment: try this - `https?:\/\/((ci|stag|ci2|ci3)|(.*\/preview)).*`

Comment: [Check this working demo](https://regex101.com/r/aKHx9g/4/tests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this in a reg-ex, you could use:

```
url.toString().matches("https?://(?:stag|ci|ci1|ci2)\\..*|.*/preview")
```

Note: there is no need to escape the `/` characters.

`(?: ... )` creates a non-capturing group.

But assuming you have a `URL`, then you might wish to use:

```
URL url = ...;
if (url.getHost().matches("(?:stag|ci|ci1|ci2)\\..*") ||
    url.getPath().endsWith("/preview")) {
}
```

which will protect against matching against the wrong portions of the URL.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `String.contains(/*something*/)`:

```
if(url.contains("/preview") || url.contains("ci") /*and the other 
    things that you want to check*/){
    //do things accordingly 
}
```